# Why do i only see QUIC and not UDP during capture in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, udp

I've been using wireshark and noticed that I no longer see UDP but QUIC, why is this the case?

Comment: I used udp as filter, but all the packets that I see are quic protocol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wireshark uses dissectors and lua scripts to analyze and classify capture traffic (or parts thereof).  What is displayed in the *Protocol* field of Wireshark's *Packet List Pane* is the information returned that is most specific after analyzing the data and will determine how the data is presented.

If the UDP dissector is the most specific dissector for the captured data, than the *Protocol* column will show UDP. However many types of UDP traffic will be identified (SIP, RTP, DNS, etc).

The same is true for TCP traffic as well. Typically you will see this as HTTP, FTP, IRC, etc.

> I've using wireshark and noticed that I no longer see UDP but QUIC, why is this the case?

In your case because the traffic has been analyzed as QUIC data. It may or may not be QUIC traffic; no program of this type is perfect, but Wireshark will be correct more often than not.

QUIC is one of the "newer" classifications, as it appears to have been added in 1.11.3/1.12.0. If you were using a version of Wireshark prior to these versions, the same traffic may likely have been classified as UDP (or another protocol).

If you don't want the QUIC protocol to be identified, simply go to the "Analyze" menu and select "Enabled Protocols" from the list. Find the entry for QUIC and uncheck the box.

Answer (score 3):

[QUIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC) runs atop UDP, so a QUIC packet *is* a (normal) UDP packet.

Wireshark currently treats all UDP packets to or from ports 80 and 443 as QUIC packets - even if they aren't.  Are the UDP packets in question going to or from one of those ports?  And *are* they, in fact, QUIC?

Answer (score 1):

If you see QUIC, you *are* seeing UDP. Unless you are sending UDP segments without QUIC, you won't see only UDP.

From [A UDP-Based Secure and Reliable Transport for HTTP/2 draft-tsvwg-quic-protocol-02](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-tsvwg-quic-protocol-02):

> QUIC (Quick UDP Internet Connection) is a new multiplexed and
> secure    transport atop UDP, designed from the ground up and
> optimized for